# CSS change heading h1 tag into logo

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replace this

`<h1><a href="itw1.html"><span>FITLayout</span></a></h1>`

line with logo whitch should be placed after my top menu with fixed position. But when I apply my CSS code, nothing is displayed.

This is how I'm trying to apply CSS code:

```
#header .inner h1 a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    background:url('https://www.google.cz/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiJxavlxfLLAhVBORQKHbAaB2MQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdesign.ubuntu.com%2Fdownloads%3Fmetadata%3Delement-logo%2Bbrand-ubuntu&psig=AFQjCNGNBTguZJPq3hjdH5AHeMs-P7V1dQ&ust=1459775537916571') no-repeat;
}

#header .inner h1 span {
    display: none;
}
```

[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/bimbochobot/eoadud8r/8/) is example of my problem and I can modify only CSS code.

Is there any solution, please?

Comment: as answered , you need to size a else it has no size. https://jsfiddle.net/eoadud8r/14/

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if your image path was valid ? Because it isn't.

[Check this code with a correct image path](https://jsfiddle.net/eoadud8r/10/)

```
#header .inner h1 a {
    display: block;
  background:url('http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1') no-repeat;
  width: 100%; height: 200px;
}
```

**EDIT**

Now, if you want the image to be fixed, you have to add `position: fixed;` and specify a `width` and `height`. You also have to add a `padding-top` to the list to make it visible.

[Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/eoadud8r/13/)

```
#header .inner h1 a {
    display: block;
  background:url('http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1') no-repeat;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  left:8px; right: 0;
}

#menubar { padding-top: 200px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

With the only child `<span>` set to `display:none` the parent `<a>` tag has zero width and height. You can manually set the `width` and `height` based on the background image size.

```css
h1 a {
  background: url('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png') no-repeat;
  display: block;
  width: 272px;
  height: 92px;
}
h1 a span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1><a href="itw1.html"><span>FITLayout</span></a></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use a pseudo element to load your image :

```css
#body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 900px;
}

#header {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

#header .inner div {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #5f5f5f;
}

#header .inner #topmenu .login {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: -10px;
    color: white;
}

#header .inner h1 a {
    float: left;
  }
#header  .inner h1 a:before {
  content:url('http://design.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/ubuntu-brandmark-thumb2.png');
}

#header .inner h1 span {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
<header id="header">
 <div class="inner">
  <h1><a href="itw1.html"><span>FITLayout</span></a></h1>
 
  <div id="topmenu">
      <a href="#" class="login">Login</a>
  </div>
  
  <div id="social" class="icons">
   <a href="http://twitter.com/" class="twitter"><span>Twitter</span></a>
   <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" class="fb"><span>Facebook</span></a>
   <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/" class="linkedin"><span>Linked In</span></a>
  </div>
 
  <nav id="menubar">
  <ul id="menu">
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Company</a></li>
      <li class="selected dropdown"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>
</header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the css rules you following things are to be made sure:-

1. "#header .inner h1 a" rule should be having a "height", "width" property, especially when you want to display image using "background" attribute.
2. Be sure the image path you have declared is correct.

#header .inner h1 a {
    background: #eee url('http://design.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/ubuntu-logo32.png') no-repeat;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 50px;
}

This should do the trick.